# Inserting Data as DD/MM/YYYY into mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I have a mysql File which contains date as

```
INSERT INTO attendance
  (Name,sTime,VerifyFlag)
VALUES('Adam','8/27/2016 12:07 PM','Fingerpint');
```

When I run the command **sTime column** which is a **datetime(6)** I get the date and time  as **(0000-00-00 00:00:00)**

I have thousands of queries as above and it's gona take lot of time if a change all the date type in YYYY/MM/DD. So my question is: Is there any way I can change this when inserting into mysql table without changing all the date manully??

Comment: What you are trying to insert in your thousand rows.. ?? Is it date or datetime ? How you are getting date/datetime input ? from other table or user input ?

Comment: @jWeaver as i metioned i'm trying to insert these (INSERT INTO attendance
  (Name,sTime,VerifyFlag)
VALUES('Adam','8/27/2016 12:07 PM','Fingerpint'); ) query into a mysql table . it's datetime , which is a exported mysql file from an attendance software .

Comment: I got that, but you have also mentioned about thousand rows.. so you all thousand rows will contain same data ?

Comment: when i insert these query into mysql i get the datetime as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @jWeaver yes all the data are in the same format

Comment: If it's a one-time operation, you can do the following: import the dates in a `VARCHAR` column. Then create a `DATETIME` column and use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert them into proper dates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column `sTime` has date-time data type define :

Try this

```
INSERT INTO attendance
  (Name,sTime,VerifyFlag)
VALUES('Adam',STR_TO_DATE('8/27/2016 12:07:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'),'Fingerpint');
```